# Select multiple Exact Online administrations based upon query

Tags: exact-online, invantive-sql

When you have many partitions (Exact Online administrations) like 2500, it can become quite cumbersome to select the right companies out of this list one-by-one and then copy & paste it into a large `use COMPANY1, COMPANY2, COMPANY3, ...` statement.

How can I more efficiently select a number of Exact Online administrations?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two more efficient ways to select a larger list of Exact Online companies from the available ones.

With `[listagg][1]` you can create a string that contains all relevant companies, such as for all companies associated with your office in the city of Amersfoort:

```
select listagg(divisionclasses_divisionclassname_divisionclassnames_administration_code_attr ) 
from   ministrationclassifications 
where  divisionclasses_divisionclassname_divisionclassnames_administration_currency_code_attr = 'EUR' 
and    divisionclasses_divisionclassname_description = 'Vestiging' 
and    description = 'Amersfoort'
```

And then copy & paste the output after the `use` statement.

In more recent versions of Invantive SQL you can also use the following [syntax](https://documentation.invantive.com/2017R2/invantive-bridge/webhelp/invantive-sql-grammar.html#usestatement):

```
use select divisionclasses_divisionclassname_divisionclassnames_administration_code_attr from ministrationclassifications where divisionclasses_divisionclassname_divisionclassnames_administration_currency_code_attr = 'EUR' and divisionclasses_divisionclassname_description = 'Vestiging' and description = 'Amersfoort'
```

This selects all companies associated with your office in the city of Amersfoort and EURO as currency.